# count different value in column, put into new columns [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I've been looking for a tutorial everywhere but I couldn't find any specific solution to this. Does anybody know how to query from this table:

```
//////////////////
places  //  type /
//////////////////
alabama //  ZX  //
alabama //  AQ  //
africa  //  AQ  //
vietnam //  FD  //
vietnam //  FD  //
////////////////
```

into this

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
places |      ZX       |     AQ      |     FD
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
alabama|      1        |      2      |     0
africa |      0        |      1      |     0
vietnam|      0        |      0      |     2
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

EDIT: I edited the format, sorry for the error earlier.

Comment: Welcome, what you are doing is called a pivot query.  Best implementation depends on database engine, what are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server)?

Comment: @Zerodf Thanks for reaching back to me. In this case, I am using MySQL.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that works across a variety of database engines.

```
-- Start: Setup Data
CREATE TABLE things (
  places VARCHAR(50), 
  type VARCHAR(50)
);  

INSERT INTO things VALUES ('alabama','ZX');
INSERT INTO things VALUES ('alabama','AQ');
INSERT INTO things VALUES ('africa','AQ');
INSERT INTO things VALUES ('vietnam','FD');
INSERT INTO things VALUES ('vietnam','FD');
-- End:  Setup Data

SELECT
  things.places,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN things.type = 'ZX' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END 
  ) AS ZX_COUNT,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN things.type = 'AQ' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END 
  ) AS AQ_COUNT,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN things.type = 'FD' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END 
  ) AS FD_COUNT
FROM things
GROUP BY things.places
```

The drawback to this solution is that you need to know a priori which columns you want to have in your pivot table.

Here is an very well thought out [answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).